# Evaluating a limit involving an integral with a non-smooth function

Tags: calculus

First time here, so I'm sorry if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find an answer to this specific integral :(

So...

I want to evaluate this limit:

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \int_0^t \dfrac{x^d}{e^x-1}\,dx.$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In wolfram alpha,  I obtained the indefinite integral as http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=x%5Ed%2F%28E%5Ex-1%29&random=false.

Comment: Well, I know the integral by itself can't be solved analytically, unless it is from 0 to infinity, where you get d! times riemann's zeta function of (d+1). However, I was hoping that when evaluating the limit it would be possible to solve said limit. I was expecting to have some luck ( :P ), because this limit is just part of a bigger expression, and I know what it should give me, because there are other ways to solve it. I was trying to avoid those ways because they require more approximations than this one :/

Comment: What do we know about $d$?

Comment: d is a natural number (not counting 0).

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
The integral converges whenever $\ds{\Re\pars{d - 1} > -1\ \imp\ \Re\pars{d} > 0}$:
\begin{align}
\mbox{For}\quad t\gtrsim 0:\quad\int_{0}^{t}{x^{d} \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x
\sim \int_{0}^{t}x^{d - 1}\,\dd x={t^{d} \over d} \stackrel{t \to 0}{\Huge\to}{\large 0}\,,\qquad\Re\pars{d} > 0
\end{align}